# Attribute Not Fount

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a circular image view but when I build the project there is an error occurring with some of the attributes:

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Questions of poor quality attract downvotes and are closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to reading the article linked by @LalitFauzdar, make sure you post your code in the question and not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 3.0.0 of the CircularImageView, the `civ_fill_color` property of the CircularImageView has been changed with `civ_circle_background_color`, use it as `app:civ_circle_background_color`.

Reference: [Version 3.0.0 does not have app:civ_fill_color #334](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/334#issuecomment-522563117)